# Android studio API integration using volley in kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley

I am new to android development and I am facing an issue in consuming a simple rest API that i have developed using asp.net, the api works fine, I have tested the api in postman as well it works absolute fine.

This is the url:

> http://localhost:5150/api/controller/1

Tthis url works fine in postman. But android gives me an error:cannot connect to `localhost`, I have tried replacing the `localhost` with my IP address eg: `199.199.0.166`, the url goes like `http://199.199.0.166:5150/api/controller/1`. However I am not able to consume it in my application, this is the api response `{"id":"1","name":"john","number":"123456"}`. Now i have to show these name and number values in my app using volley library.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
val url = "http://199.199.0.166:5150/api/controller/1"

val jsonRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, 
    url,
    null,
    Response.Listener {
        val name = it.getString("name")
        val number = it.getString("number")

        username.text = name
        phone.text = number

    },
    Response.ErrorListener{
        Toast.makeText(activity,it.message.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
) {
    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String,String>()
        headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        return headers
    }
}
queue.add(jsonRequest)
```

this gives me an error as "null" after starting the application, I have also tried the string request but the result goes the same...

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: android studio doesnt give any error, when I navigate to the fragment where the response is to displayed, a toast message appears as null, i.e it goes to the response error listener block